# Google Spreadsheet importing CSV with arbitrary date formatting?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I'm trying to figure out what are the options for dealing with CSV file which has inconsistent locale dates formatting? The spreadsheet set to recognize MMM-dd-yyyy as a valid date (via spreadsheet settings) and CSV file has dd-MMM-yyyy. a) Can I write a custom CSV loader which will process/fix the data before putting it into a spreadsheet? b) Can I access (via API) a raw cell text (avoiding automatically converted 'wrong' date string) and fix it as necessary? c) any other solution? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Just noticed that even if I use a proper locale with default dd/MMM/yyyy (like Spain) the spreadsheet importer ignores it and uses some default locale settings. So it shows a cell with 22/09/2012 and doesn't recognize it as a date cell but if I type in the next cell the same 22/09/2012 it converts it to proper Spain locale... which is annoying.

Comment: ...and some more goodness. With correct dd/MMM/yyyy locale the spreadsheet treats 06/05/2012 as a valid date and converts it to a Date object, but skips 30/05/2012 and leaves it as a string.

Comment: Well.. I found a 'crutch' solution for this problem which allows to read csv and process it within a spreadsheet (though locale needs to be set correctly). The trick is a simple function which overwrites all date column cells with same values. Which is a bit stupid code... but works fine.

Answer (score 4):

If you write your own script to produce CSV, make your dates in this format and then Google Sheets will automatically recognize them and you can format them however you want:

```
YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss
```

Here's an example date (January 22, 2020 at 1:34:22pm):

```
2020-01-22 13:34:22
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there's a nice solution to this problem. But I can imagine some workarounds that might work for you.

1. You could upload the file without converting to your Google Docs/Drive and then have a [Google Apps Script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/) read it [and load into your spreadsheet](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/articles/docslist_tutorial).
2. Or you could just insert an apostrophe before each date using a regular text editor on your computer, doing a search and replace. The apostrophe prevents the content of a cell of being parsed by the spreadsheet and is left as is (i.e. a text).

Comment: Yeah.. but that means I need to perform manually some extra steps, which I try to avoid. By the way, I found an ugly solution which, nevertheless, resolves the issue.

Comment: Did you happen to find any solution to this? I have the same issue

Answer (score 0):

Specifically for csv with dates dd/mm/yyyy, one option is to manually add a column next to it and use this formula to convert the cells:

```
=if(isblank(A2),"",if(isdate(A2),date(year(A2),day(A2),month(A2)),if(len(A2)=10,date(value(mid(A2,7,4)),value(mid(A2,4,2)),value(mid(A2,1,2))),"error")))
```

It's not elegant, not very practical (needs manual editing), but maybe it suits your needs.